# Cron job not working in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, cron, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am facing some issue with cron job in Yii2 application.
I am define Controller in console as follow

```
namespace console\controllers;
use yii\console\Controller;
/**
 * Job controller
 */
class JobController extends Controller {

public function actionIndex() {
    echo "cron service runnning";
    mail("mail@gmail.com","Cron",'Testing');
}

}
```

Path in cpenal is
php /home/user/public_html/root/ yii job

I always receiving email with error

Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38
Content-type: text/html

No input file specified.

I think there is issue with cmd supplied for it.
Please help me to sort out this issue.
Thankyou

Comment: A console controller is meant to be called from terminal, not via Webbrowser. You should do sth like `./yii job/index` (or yii.bat on windows) in your project directory

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.

Answer (score 0):

1.show system crontab log

why you do not use yii\swiftmailer\Mailer

```
$components = [
                'mailer' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
                    'useFileTransport' => false, 
                    'transport' => [
                        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                        'host' => 'smtp.xxx.com',
                        'username' => 'xx@xxx.com',
                        'password' => 'xxx',
                        'port' => '25',
                        'encryption' => 'tls',
                    ],
                    'messageConfig' => [ 
                        'charset' => 'UTF-8', 
                        'from' => ['xx@xx.com' => 'contents'] 
                    ],
                ]
            ];
            Yii::$app->setComponents($components);
            $mail= Yii::$app->mailer->compose(); 
            $mail->setTo(['from@xxx.com', 'to@xx.com']); 
            $mail->setSubject($subject); 
            $mail->setHtmlBody($content); 
            $mail->send();
```